# IDE and library and Makefile

Tags: c++, ide, makefile

if I wrote some files named file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp and so on.  and file1.cpp need library l1, file2.cpp need l2 , file3.cpp need l3. 
  should we write the makefile line by line? 
  and seems IDE still can't detect which library our program use. 
  so how to let IDE/{any thing}  to detect library automatically?

Thanks for your apply!

Comment: More often then not you make a rule for `.cpp` files in general which exposes provides the include for the libraries, and a linking stage which provides all the libs.

Comment: Are you having trouble *compiling* (when the compiler must know where to find the headers of `l1`), or *linking* (when the linker must know which libraries to use and where to find them)?

Comment: Thanks both of you!  Because I just write some small codes, I compile and link in one step. I will think and try more about your answer.